# Loop through taxonomy parents

Tags: taxonomy-terms, 8

How can i loop through taxonomy in drupal 8.
I found this static function but TID is required, how can i loop through all taxonomy without using TID?

```
Drupal::entityManager()->getStorage('taxonomy_term')->loadAllParents($tid);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out myself by looping through the table using the database api

```
public function getTaxonomy(){
  $query = db_query("SELECT * FROM taxonomy_term_field_data");

  $taxonomy = [];

  foreach($query as $val){
    $taxonomy[] = array(
        'tid' => $val->tid,
        'vid' => $val->vid,
        'name' => $val->name
      );
  }

  return $taxonomy;      

}
```

EDIT : Yet better solution with api instead of using manual SQL query, as per Eyal suggestion.

```
public function getTaxonomy(){

  $terms = \Drupal::database()->select('taxonomy_term_field_data', 'td')->fields('td')->execute()->fetchAll();

  $taxonomy = [];

  foreach($terms as $val){
    $taxonomy[] = array(
        'tid' => $val->tid,
        'vid' => $val->vid,
        'name' => $val->name
      );
  }

  return $taxonomy;      

}
```

Comment: You should use drupal services like so \Drupal::database()->select('taxonomy_term_field_data')->execute()

Comment: unfortunately, this gives me error 'The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.'

Comment: I forgot the fields method. Try the following: \Drupal::database()->select('taxonomy_term_field_data', 'td')->fields('td')->execute()->fetchAll()  I'm writing this from my phone out of memory, if you want more complex solutions then read the documentation on the database connection class.

Comment: Yup, now i got everything i need and it works perfect! No more manual SQL statement necessary. Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 2):

I think you are using the word "parent" incorrectly.

The terms of a vocabulary can be sorted in a tree. And the parents of a specific term are the ones higher in that hierachy. So, if you want all parents of a term, of course you need so say, which term and give its id as $tid.

However, if you just want all terms of a taxonomy, you can use loadTree($vid) instead. $vid is the id of your vocabulary.

If you want to load all taxonomy terms, ignoring which vocabulary they belong to, then this is the best solution:

```
$terms = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('taxonomy_term')->loadMultiple();
```

Then, to access the term data do

```
foreach ($terms as $term) {
    $tid = $term->id();
    $vid = $term->getVocabularyId();
    $name = $term->getName();
}
```

If all you need is the ids of all the terms, this is enough:

```
$tids = \Drupal::entityQuery('taxonomy_term')->execute();
```

Comment: Hi Mouna, the objective is to retrieve all taxonomy parents without having to know their ID. it's more like "SELECT * FROM table" and loop through it.

Comment: I think you should not say all taxonomy **parents** but taxonomy **terms**.
Does 
\Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('taxonomy_term')->loadTree($vocabulary_id);
not return what you need?

Comment: $vocabulary_‌​id this is what i cannot foreseen or know the value, it could be anything. So the solution should be without passing parameter similar to "SELECT * FROM table" and loop through it.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, instead of all taxonomy **parents** you want all taxonomy **vocabularies**.
How about this then:
$vocabularies = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('taxonomy_vocabulary')->loadMultiple();
or
$vocabularies = \Drupal::entityQuery('taxonomy_vocabulary')->execute();

Comment: Thanks. i tried using both but none of them give me the tid.